# When using reflex to run Go server Mac repeatedly asks to accept network connections

Tags: macos, go

I have a Go API I am trying to test and I've installed reflex. It gets up and running just fine, but every time I save my project it creates a new instance of the application. It will prompt my system to ask for permissions:

```
Do you want the application “go-api” to accept incoming network connections?
Clicking Deny may limit the application’s behavior. 
This setting can be changed in the Firewall pane of Security & Privacy preferences.
```

Would really appreciate any help or even some guidance on how to troubleshoot as I haven't seen anything about this bug yet.

When I check my Mac's privacy and security settings, I can see that the firewall allows an instance of go-api along with many other instances of go-api.

When I reveal these applications in my finder I can see that Go is instantiating separate build files for each instance of my program and creating a Unix executable file to serve as the application.

On my coworker's devices that have installed Go and reflex for the same API, this behavior is not present. I do not think it is related to the reflex config or the API because theirs are exactly the same as mine is, but not exhibiting the same behavior.

I am thinking that this may be related to my .bash_profile or something:

```
# Setting PATH for Go
export GOPATH="$HOME/go"
PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/me/Documents/path/to/go-api
export GO_ENV=dev
```

Comment: UPDATE: I scrapped reflex and tried with Gin and the issue persists, but behaves a little differently. Now, I must send a request to localhost:3000 and respond to the same prompt before sending requests to my server on localhost:8080. This tells me that it is not an issue with Reflex or Gin, but most likely *does* relate to my local environment, system settings, or GOPATH, but I still haven't found how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I found a solution, albeit an unsatisfying one. According to Apple:

> If you run an unsigned app that is not listed in the firewall list, a dialog appears with options to Allow or Deny connections for the app. If you choose Allow, OS X signs the application and automatically adds it to the firewall list. If you choose Deny, OS X adds it to the list but denies incoming connections intended for this app.
>   -- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201642

So, I turned off Firewall because I haven't found a way to single out my application and allow it while still keeping the firewall up.